# Joining two SQL tables in Microsoft SQL server 2012 to get a certain format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join two SQL tables:

- Department

  ```
   Department Name     Total Hours
        Office            70
          IT              80
  ```

  ---
- Employee

  ```
     Employee Name     Total Hours   Department
        Amy                20          OFFICE
        John               30          OFFICE
        Jack               20          OFFICE
        Lucy               25          IT
        Louise             55          IT
  ```

---

I want the results to show the department totals followed by the employees in that department e.g.

```
              Total Hours
   OFFICE       70
   Amy          20
   John         30
   Jack         20
   IT           80
   Lucy         25
   Louise       55
```

I know how to join tables to get results. I just don't know how to get the above format.

Comment: Could you give us a more detailed description of your two tables? We need to know the table structure if we're to answer this properly.

Comment: "I know how to join tables to get results. I just don't know how to get the above format." => "We know how to get the above format, we don't know how to join your tables to get results"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  e.Department_ID ,
        e.Employee_Name AS Col1 ,
        e.Total_Hours
FROM    Employee e
UNION ALL
SELECT  d.Department_ID ,
        d.Department_Name AS Col1 ,
        SUM(e.Total_Hours)
FROM    Employee e
        JOIN Department d ON e.Department_ID = d.Department_ID
GROUP BY d.Department_ID ,
        d.Department_Name
ORDER BY Department_ID ASC ,
        Total_Hours DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67e4c1/13/0)

Based on provided table structure and sample data, I feel that you may want to redesign your table something similar to my example above. It seems to violate the normal form and seems to be missing primary key in your tables. I strongly urge you to redesign your table so it saves you some headaches in the future. Meanwhile, here is how you can achieve your desired output:

```
SELECT  e.Employee_Name AS Col1 ,
        e.Total_Hours,
        e.Department_Name as Sort_Field
FROM    Employee e
UNION ALL
SELECT  d.Department_Name AS Col1 ,
        d.Total_Hours,
        UPPER(d.Department_Name) as Sort_Field     
FROM   Department d
ORDER BY Sort_Field,Total_Hours desc
```

[Sample Data Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7825/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to display specific data from a query, you can specify which columns you want to display. Instead of using `SELECT * FROM` you would write:

```
SELECT table1.column, table2.column
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.id
```

If your table is `Department` and the column is `Hours` for the first field, then you want to display `Department.Hours`. If your table is `Employees` and the column is `EmployeeName` for the second, then you are going to display `Department.EmployeeName`.

You can select as many columns from as many tables as you want, just separate them with commas after the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Office], [Total Hours] from Department d join Employees e on d.id = e.id
order by [Office] ASC
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.